# Color and background button not appear in my CKEditor Widget Template

Tags: widget, ckeditor

I Create a CKEditor Widget and the color and background color not enable when I Select for example a paragraphe.

Here is my widget

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add( 'applivewidget', {
    requires: 'widget',

    icons: 'applivewidgetLeftCol,applivewidgetRightCol,applivewidgetThreeCol,applivewidgetTwoCol',

    init: function( editor ) {
        // Configurable settings

        var allowedText =  editor.config.applivewidget_allowedText != undefined ? editor.config.applivewidget_allowedText : 'font;div{background-color};h2{color};p{color, font} [font];span;br;ul;ol;li;strong;em;h3;img{ height, width } [!src,width,height];';

        CKEDITOR.dialog.add( 'applivewidgetLeftCol', this.path + 'dialogs/applivewidget.js' );



        var showButtons = editor.config.applivewidgetShowButtons != undefined ? editor.config.applivewidgetShowButtons : true;

        // Define the widgets
        editor.widgets.add( 'applivewidgetLeftCol', {

            button: showButtons ? 'Add left column box' : undefined,
            dialog: 'applivewidgetLeftCol',
            template:
                '<div class="span_wrapper col_1_2">' +
                    '<div class="span equal edit1 span1_3 wow bounceIn"><p class="nopadding"><img src="/sites/all/themes/cefort/images/img450_375.png" /></p></div>' +
                    '<div class="span equal edit2 span2_3 wow bounceIn"><h2>Sub Title</h2><p>Content</p></div>' +
                '</div>',
            init: function() {
                var bgc = this.element.getChild(0).getStyle( 'background-color' );
                if ( bgc )
                    this.setData( 'bgc', bgc );
            }, 
            data: function() {
                if ( this.data.bgc == '' )
                {
                     this.element.getChild(0).removeStyle( 'background-color' );
                      this.element.getChild(1).removeStyle( 'background-color');
                }
                else
                {
                     this.element.getChild(0).setStyle( 'background-color', '#'+this.data.bgc );
                      this.element.getChild(1).setStyle( 'background-color', '#'+this.data.bgc );

                }


            },   
            editables: {
                col1: {
                    selector: '.edit1',
                    allowedContent: allowedText
                },
                col2: {
                    selector: '.edit2',
                    allowedContent: allowedText
                }
            },

            allowedContent: allowedText,

            upcast: function( element ) {
                return element.name == 'div' && element.hasClass( 'col_1_2' );
            }

        } );
```

I'm not able to select my text color of the previous widget.

Please help

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The issue comes from your `allowedText` content, which I seem pretty weird.

Here is its content, where I added spaces to make it more readable:

```
'font; div{background-color}; h2{color}; p{color, font} [font]; span; br; ul; ol; li; strong; em; h3; img{ height, width } [!src,width,height];'
```

First you directly quote `font`, which is no longer a valid element in HTML 5: so it has no effect here.

Then you allow `font` style and `font` attribute to `p` element: both have only a chance to be useful if some (already entered) content quotes them.  The same remark applies to `div{background-color}`, `h2{color}` and `p{color}`.

All these specifications don't meet the way CKEditor creates font or color styles variations, which is like `<span style="font-family:...">`, `<span style="font-style:...">`,  `<span style="color:...">` or `<span style="background-color:...">`.

So for your text color feature to be active you must write `span {color}`, or `span {background-color}` for background color feature, and so on.
More simply I suggest you merely write `span {*}` to have all of these features active, unless you want to specifically limit what is allowed.

Also note that you may simplify your `allowedContent` string where a number of elements share the same properties (or not property at all), like in `br ul ol li strong em h3;`.